# How do we know a nerve agent is tasteless?

Tags: safety, toxicity, taste, chemical-weapons

[According to the BBC](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/health-43328976), the nerve agent [sarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarin) is a tasteless liquid. How do we know that this liquid has no taste, given that anyone to have (not) tasted it in any meaningful quantity presumably died shortly thereafter.

Can the taste be inferred from its chemical properties?

Comment: Similar: [How do people know HCN smells like almonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47204/7951)

Comment: Roughly speaking, we know that from the unfortunate guys who tasted it and died shortly thereafter. This is a very different situation from HCN.