# How do we know if a newly developed chemical compound has any taste or is tasteless?

Tags: plastics, taste

I was reading [this](https://www3.epa.gov/ttnchie1/ap42/ch06/final/c06s06-3.pdf) about polystyrene, which says: "Polystyrene is an odorless, **tasteless**, rigid thermoplastic", and got hung up on "tasteless".

I searched Chemistry.SE for "tasteless" and found [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92000/how-do-we-know-a-nerve-agent-is-tasteless) and [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/how-do-people-know-hcn-smells-like-almonds), but they don't exactly answer my question in the title, because polystyrene is not considered a poison and is not a natural compound. So for such a highly-used, man-made, industrial-scale-manufactured compound, how do we know its taste (or lack of it)? Was the data acquired in an official way, through intended testing, or only from "accidents" (which I cannot imagine, so just for the sake of argument)?

Comment: Not an answer but a fun bit - in 1935 Harold Urey published a short bit in Science on 'Concerning the Taste of Heavy Water' (there was no difference between distilled water and pure heavy water, if you are interested).

Comment: I'm trying to remember where I saw this, but I'm pretty sure I ran into a paper from the early 1900s where part of the experimental said something along the lines of "[compound] has characteristic taste of [some class of compounds]". Good thing that class of compounds was not strychnoids...

Comment: Historically, many compounds were tasted for sure. For what is happening nowadays, I suspect that first the level of toxicity is determined. Obviously the taste of most of the immense number of new compounds prepared each day will remain unknown :)