# HCN, or my nose says I'm dead

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, safety

As you see, I still post...

I studied chemisty decades ago (and when I was through with all the compulsory practica, I was sent to a computer chemistry workgroup and politely suggested to never touch a beaker again, which I happily followed and made my PhD there, otherwise probably the chemistry dept. of the university of Hamburg would no longer exist :-)

Here's one of my specialities as a walking disaster area. Hmmm, "Trennungsgang" seems to be nonexistent in English, make that Qualitative Inorganic Analysis. Don't ask me to remember the details, but Fe3+ is detected with NCS-. For another cation later you need H2O2. I never learnt to use a different test tube. The result were always the same - a geysir shooting out of the test tube and over my fingers (now that you say it, gloves exist) accompanied with some almond stink that suggests I just got a deadly dose of cyanide.

I'm remarkably hard to kill but methinks I rather misinterpreted the perceptions. So, maybe it only was less toxic HSCN that blew off? (I think the H2O2 solution was acidic.) BTW, Wiki says "odor pungent".

Comment: HCN as a poison is greatly overrated.

Comment: Related: [How do people know HCN smells like almonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47204/101286)

Comment: You don't get HCN from oxidation of SCN. Your reaction was mostly catalytic decomp. of H2O2.

Comment: You can get also the cyanide odor from wilting leaves of stone fruits like peaches and cherries.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Toxic Substance Portal of ATSDR](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/MMG/MMG.asp?id=1141&tid=249), "The [almond] odor of hydrogen cyanide is detectable at 2-10 ppm (OSHA PEL = 10 ppm), but does not provide adequate warning of hazardous concentrations. Perception of the odor is a genetic trait (20% to 40% of the general population cannot detect hydrogen cyanide)." However, from that same source, the NIOSH IDLH (immediately dangerous to life or health) is 50 ppm, so *if* your among the ~70% who *can* smell $\ce{HCN}$, you could note an odor and have a safety factor of ~10 before *immediate* death occurs. Of course, the smell is less noticeable as the sense of smell fatigues, and *long term effects* are another question.

As to whether you smelled thiocyanic acid, $\ce{HSCN}$, [its odor is described as "pungent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiocyanic_acid), not at all like bitter almonds, so likely that was *not* what you smelled. Thiocyanates are about 100 times less toxic than similar cyanides, and are even [used internally in medicine](https://www.tabletwise.net/medicine/potassium-thiocyanate).

The toxicity of $\ce{HCN}$ is roughly [comparable to that of $\ce{H2S}$](http://alken-murray.com/H2SREM9.HTM), which is frequently encountered in the lab and in nature, such as at geothermal features, but since most people can sense $\ce{H2S}$ at 0.03 ppm, it is treated far  more casually.

But $\ce{HCN}$ is toxic enough that the old joke still applies. Question: "What's the difference between cyanide and *sayonara*?" Answer: "*Sayonara* means goodbye in Japanese, and cyanide means goodbye in *any* language."

Comment: In the main body of the query, the OP is asking about HSCN. The title is a typo.

Comment: @M.Farooq, reread the question: he is *unsure* if it was HCN or the relatively nontoxic thiocyanate "So, *maybe* it only was less toxic HSCN that blew off?". However, I'll add that to the answer.